# WPF - add userid as prefix to orignal mail while forwarding mail

Tags: c#, wpf

I have textbox which shows the content of mail body.
While forwarding mail original mail body if content is edited by pressing any key then user id should get appended. Please let me know how should I do this in WPF.

Comment: what have you done so far in code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Before sending the mail

```
if(edits_made) // bool value which indicates if changes have been made
{
   yourtextbox.Text.Insert(0, userid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not before sending an mail.
Similar functionality is there in outlook as well.
Add < prefix to original mail if content is modified.
Same I am trying to build in WPF.